# UIScrollView buggy

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, zooming

Please excuse poor code atm, just trying to get it working before making it look nice.  So I am trying to get UIScrollView working.  If I remove all scroll view stuff, I have a nicely laid out page with 64 buttons, 32 on each side of the page. These buttons are nigh miniature; so I wanted to implement zoom to be able to click them.

Zoom currently has unexpected results.  When the page starts, it is blank.  Zooming unexpectedly shows some of the left side of the graph on the rigght side of the page, and it bounces as I try to scroll over towards it.  But when I zoom more, it allows me to scroll more towards the middle of the buttons.  Always giving me difficulties/bugging out as I scroll/zoom.  So obviously unusable.

My viewDidLoad:

```
[super viewDidLoad];
UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
scroll.minimumZoomScale = 0.5;
scroll.maximumZoomScale = 3.0;
scroll.delegate = self;
    CGFloat yOrigin = self.view.frame.size.width;
    UIView *awesomeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(yOrigin, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

// iterate over values in the staff array
int heightBetweenBrackets = 0;
int widthBetweenBrackets = 0;
int heightFromTop = 45;

for(int i = 0; i < 64; i++)
{
    if(i == 32)
    {
        heightBetweenBrackets = 0;
    }
    UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    myButton.frame = CGRectMake(
                                0 + i/32*438,
                                heightFromTop + i%32*3+ heightBetweenBrackets, 
                                35, 6);
    [myButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    myButton.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    [myButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:7]];
    myButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
    //   [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(chooseWinner:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [awesomeView addSubview:myButton];
    heightBetweenBrackets += (i%2  -1 * -1) * 3;
}

[scroll addSubview:awesomeView];
scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:scroll];
```

and:

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return self.view;
}
```

I apologize if the bug is stupid I'm just learning IOS =] thanks for your time

EDIT: Figured it out.

For anybody in the future: I ported over a pagination scroller, and didn't realize I had kept CGFloat yOrigin = self.view.frame.size.width; -- this of course was starting the view directly to the right of any visible space. Thus I was able to zoom and see the left of it, in a buggy manner, although it started out blank.  Simply changing this to 0 solved my problem.

Comment: If you found a solution, please post it as an answer and accept it once you can.

Comment: Yeah I can't do that for 8 hours :(

Comment: That's fine, do it when you can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anybody in the future: I ported over a pagination scroller, and didn't realize I had kept CGFloat yOrigin = self.view.frame.size.width; -- this of course was starting the view directly to the right of any visible space. Thus I was able to zoom and see the left of it, in a buggy manner, although it started out blank. Simply changing this to 0 solved my problem.